# pandas reset_index() not working after applying groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Opposition':['Sri Lanka', 'Sri Lanka', 'UAE','UAE','Sri Lanka'],
                   'Inning_no':[1,2,1,2,1], 'Wickets':[13,17,14,18,29]})
```

I have the groupby to get the following output

```
t = inn.groupby(['Opposition', 'Inning_no'])['Wickets'].agg([('Wickets', 'sum'), ('Played', 'count')])
```

I have the output like this

```
                                    Wickets   Played
            Opposition  Inning_no       
            v Sri Lanka    1           42       4
                           2           17       2
            v UAE          1           14       4
                           2           18       6
```

**The problem is that reset_index() is not working with the group by**. The multi column index is set on Opposition and Innings_no column. I want the index to be reset and show all in one level like below.

[image]

I am having this error

```
ValueError: cannot insert Opposition, already exists
```

Comment: Do you mean opposition and innings should be columns and not the index and as index you want to have increasing numbers?

Comment: what is the error when you do a `.reset_index()` at the end of your code? also please post the data as text instead of images as images cant be copied

Comment: Did you try including the keyword as_index=False in the group by call?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Opposition', 'Inning_no'])['Wickets'].agg([('Wickets', 'sum'), ('Played', 'count')]).reset_index()` works fine for me

Comment: It's working fine for me as well (I just had to replace `inn` by `df`).

Comment: hell @anky it worked

Comment: @anky you can post the answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `reset_index` at the end

```
t = inn.groupby(['Opposition', 'Inning_no'])['Wickets'].agg([('Wickets', 'sum'), ('Played', 'count')]).reset_index()
```